# Running gnuplot from Matlab under Linux

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run gnuplot directly from Matlab (running in Debian Linux), but I get the following error:

```
>> unix('gnuplot defaults_loan10.p');
gnuplot: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0)
```

Running gnuplot from the console works perfectly well. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Matlab uses its own LD_LIBRARY_PATH

try to use the command `setenv` to set back this environment variable as you like.

For instance:

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH','/usr/lib')
```

You can check the content of LD_LIBRARY_PATH befor and after by executing:

```
!echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: So what should be the correct Matlab code to run? Sorry, I am not really experienced with Matlab...

Comment: Do you have experience with linux?

Comment: Just checked that this one also works: `unix('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib;gnuplot defaults_loan10.p');`

Comment: If it works that is indeed a LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue, in your case, `setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH','/lib');unix('gnuplot defaults_loan10.p');`
 should also work.